# Reading a (compressed) file

Tags: python

My code :

```
sent = str(input("Please input a sentence: "))
dl = [0]

for count , v in enumerate (splitsent):

    if splitsent.count(v) < 2:

        dl.append(max(dl) +1) 
    else:
        dl.append(splitsent.index(v) +1)

dl.remove(0)
print(sent, "\n",dl)
```

gives the output :

```
"1,2,3,4,1,2"
```

with the input:

```
"To be or not to be"
```

This is it in it's "compressed" form. How would I take the output,"1,2,3,4,1,2" from an external file and turn it into the "To be or not to be"?

Comment: How would the program know that `1` should be "to" and not "hello" or some other word? Also your code is incomplete.

Comment: You would need to specify somewhere in your file what word every number corresponds to.

Comment: I understand my code is incomplete. This reads a user input and puts it into that format. The to be or not to be is just an example. It can read repeated words with the same enumeration. I need assistance in making this code read the output of numbers and converting it into the words.

Comment: @Racialz This was my thoughts originally, would I save them as a list after importing the "key" from another file?

Comment: I think you should use a dict like such `wordList = {1:"hello", 2:"world", 3:"test123"}` that way when you read them back you can use `wordList[1]` to display the word that number 1 represents. You can even use json to write your list to file and then read it back

Comment: Code without proper indentation cannot be python code. It's not a matter of style. Please correct your indentation. And as for what you want to do, you need a compression algorithm, there are lots of them. Read the pseudo-code. **There is no point talking about how you want to do something without knowing what it is you want to do.**  Implementation will follow naturally.

Comment: Yeah. Would it be possible to do so in such a way that it would take the enumeration from the characters previously written and convert that to a list. Though be imported? Maybe import the file and do file.split() for both? Would I then be able to put that in a dictionary?

Comment: @CPanda apologies I have corrected my mistake

Comment: @AshleyPeterThomas `splitsent.index(v)` and `enumerate` should not coexist. It's redundant. No need for apologies.

Comment: @CPanda maybe you can help. The code above I am happy with. I need some help with writing it so that the enumeration is saved to another file, and then can be read on the program and given the sentence. So if the input from a file was "1,2,3,4,1,2" the output from the code would be:"To be or not to be"

Comment: @AshleyPeterThomas well. I am not very familiar with compression algorithms. They tend to store the indices and words avoiding redundancy. Please check out a simple algorithm,so that you can extrapolate from that.

Answer (score 0):

Your method really not an efficient way of compressing a text file, just use the existing [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html).

But, for the academic exercise, you will want to use pickle to store your dictionary keys such that when you recover it you get the same values.  As you want the 'compressed' form to exist between invocations, so that you can successfully decompress a previously 'compressed' file, you will need to allocate an index to each word. 
If you want a 'standard' python method, OrderedDict from collections can be used to create an index in this way, new words are added to the end, but unlike conventional dict objects, old ones keep their position.  A better method is an OrderedSet, but this is not in standard python, see [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/).

**Case**
You also have to decide if 'THIS', 'this' and 'ThIs' are different words or the same word.  Perhaps each word token needs a bitfield to indicate if each character is lower or upper case, e.g. 'ThIs' gets a token 15, but a bitfield of 5 "0x1010", producing a tuple of (15,5) in the compressed file.

**Punctuation**
You will also need to consider punctuation, where a word is thus punctuated you will need a way to represent this in the compressed form, a token for the punctuation character.
But there is a problem with this.
Then when you decompress you will need to recreate the original exactly, so handle punctuation.  e.g. "Is this correct?" -> [1,2,3,4] -> "Is this correct ?" or "Is this correct?" without the space.
So for each punctuation you need to indicate how it joins to the previous and next character, e.g. 
As punctuation is only ever one character (i.e. one 8 bit number), you may want to consider just putting the character as-is.

**Multiple spaces**
You will also need to handle multiple spaces.

**Example code**
This code is incomplete, mostly untested and probably does not handle all use cases, but it illustrates one possible solution to the question.

To use it, create a file called in.txt containing the text you want to compress, then run
python compdict.py -c in.txt out.comp
or
python compdict.py -d out.comp out.txt
or
python compdict.py --list

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet #pip install ordered_set
import os
import cPickle as pickle
import string
import argparse

class CompDecomp(object):
  __DEFAULT_PICKLE_FN__ = "my.dict"

  printable_non_chars = set(string.printable) - set(string.digits) - set(string.ascii_letters)

  def __init__(self, fn=None, *args, **kw):
    if fn is None:
      self.fn = self.__DEFAULT_PICKLE_FN__
    else:
      self.fn = fn

    self.dict = self.loaddict()

  def loaddict(self):
    if os.path.exists(self.fn):
      pkl = open(self.fn, "rb")
      d = pickle.load(pkl)
      pkl.close()
    else:
      d = OrderedSet()
    return d

  def savedict(self):
      pkl = open(self.fn, "wb")
      pickle.dump(self.dict, pkl)
      pkl.close()

  def compressword(self, word, conjoin=False):
    if word.lower() not in self.dict:
      self.dict.append(word.lower())
      print "New word: \'%s\'" % word
      self.savedict()
    index, flag, _ = self.__caseflag__(word, conjoin)
    #print index, bin(flag)[2:].zfill(len(word)), conjoin
    return index, flag, conjoin

  def decompressword(self, index, caseflag=0, conjoin=False):
    if isinstance(index, int):
      word = self.dict[index]
    else:
      word = index
    if caseflag == 0:
      return word, conjoin
    flag = bin(caseflag)[2:].zfill(len(word))
    res = ""
    for n, c in enumerate(word):
      if flag[n] == '1':
        res += c.upper()
      else:
        res += c.lower()
    return res, conjoin

  def __caseflag__(self, word, conjoin):
    index = self.dict.index(word.lower())
    if word.lower() == word:
      #Word is all lowercase
      return (index,0, conjoin)
    if word.upper() == word:
      #Word is all uppercase
      return index, int("1" * len(word), 2), conjoin
    res = ""
    for c in word:
      if c in string.uppercase:
        res += "1"
      else:
        res += "0"
    return index, int(res, 2), conjoin

  def compressfile(self, fileobj):
    with fileobj as f:
      data = f.read(-1)
      f.close()

    words = data.split(" ")

    compress = []
    for word in words:
      #Handle multiple spaces
      if word == "":
        compress.append(" ")
        continue

      #Handle puntuation, treat apostrophied words as new words
      substr = []
      p1 = 0
      csplit = word.translate(None, string.ascii_letters+'\'')
      for n, c in enumerate(csplit):
        subword, word = word.split(c, 1)
        compress.append(self.compressword(subword, True if n > 0 else False))
        compress.append((c, 0, True))

      #Handle words
      if len(word) and not len(csplit):
        compress.append(self.compressword(word))
    return compress

  def decompressfile(self, fileobj):
    data = pickle.load(fileobj)

    decomp = ""
    for v in data:
      if not isinstance(v,tuple):
        print "Bad data %s" % v
        continue
      if len(v) > 0 and len(v) <= 3:
        d, conjoin = self.decompressword(*v)
        if len(decomp):
          decomp += "" if conjoin else " "
        decomp += d
      else:
        print "Bad data %s (length %d)" % (v, len(v))
    return decomp


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test file compress / decompress')

  group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
  parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', default=None)
  parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', default=None)
  group.add_argument('-compress', action='store_true')
  group.add_argument('-decompress', action='store_true')
  group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true')

  args = parser.parse_args()

  cd = CompDecomp()

  #Invocation
  #python dictcompress.py [-h|-c|-d|--list] [<infile>] [<outfile>]
  infile, outfile = args.infile, args.outfile

  if infile is not None and not os.path.exists(infile):
    print "Input file missing"

  if outfile is not None:
    of = open(outfile, "wb")
  else:
    of = None

  if not args.list:
    if args.compress:
      print "Compress"
      pickle.dump(cd.compressfile(open(infile, "r")), of)

    if args.decompress:
      print "Decompress"
      of.write(cd.decompressfile(open(infile, "r")))
  else:
    for k in cd.dict:
      print k

  if of is not None:
    of.close()
```